# Sleep but with interval update

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, sleep, intervals, time-wait

I am using Visual Basic.net with a BackGround Worker. I am wanting to wait for x milliseconds but to update a Label with the current wait value.

How can I do this?

I am using this code at the moment:

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

What else can I use as the above code does not inform me of the sleep progress?

Comment: You need a Timer or something like  Crypt shows. Sleep puts the whole app to sleep so that a label cant update.

Comment: @Plutonix `Sleep()` only affects the current thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean, but here is a similar code to yours. Hope it helps!

```
Dim EndTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(TimeToWaitInSeconds)
While DateTime.Now < EndTime
    Application.DoEvents()
End While
```